# Regex find a word into attribute

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a case like this:

```
<p class="definitione **form**">Data una grandezza indica la variazione.</p><br/>
<p class="**form**">Due casi molto comuni sono:</p><br/>
<ul><br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<li class="**form** placeholder">è il valore iniziale della grandezza.</li><br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<li class="definition **form** placeholder">è il valore di in un secondo punto.</li><br/>
</ul><br/>
<p id="form">Se la grandezza aumenta, la variazione è positiva</p><br/><br/>
```

I need to find (and replace) only form word (and not the other word) into attribute class.

Try with this regex:

```
(?<=class=")form(?=")
```

select only:

```
<p class="definitione form">Data una grandezza indica la variazione.</p><br/>
<p class="**form**">Due casi molto comuni sono:</p><br/>
<ul><br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<li class="form placeholder">è il valore iniziale della grandezza.</li><br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<li class="definition form placeholder">è il valore di in un secondo punto.</li><br/>
</ul><br/>
<p id="form">Se la grandezza aumenta, la variazione è positiva</p><br/><br/>
```

But I need to select ALL **form** in all class attribute

Comment: While your specific problem might be solvable with a regex, be aware of this: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/256544)

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, well, it's not really a question - more a statement. Are you trying to select elements with a class of `form` when that is the only class? (so `form spec` wouldn't match)

Comment: Hi SmokeyPHP, sorry for grammar and error, I change the body of statement! I need to find only the word FORM into quotation mark.

Comment: Bill the Lizard, thank you so much! Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match classes with `form` in them:

```
(class="[^"]*)(form)([^"]*")
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/IWcJ7rBwi3) of this regex, which uses look arounds to assert what precedes and follows the target.

Note that group 2 matches "form", not the whole expression. This is because variable length look behinds are illegal. Your replacement should refer to group 1 and 3 to put them back.

Comment: Yes, but I need to find **form** when there is another word too, find ALL **form** into ALL class attribute, independently if it's "alone"...

Comment: Follow the link to the live demo and tell me what examples it fails to work correctly with. Add more examples if you like and post the new link as a comment here.

Comment: I've edited the answer to match form anywhere in the class. Group 2 is your match